# PyQT Buttons has Incorrect Size in QGridLayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt

I just started a simple PyQt app on Windows 7 and Python 2.7. There are 2 buttons and a table. The Apple button should be 5x taller that the Orange button, and the table should be the same height as the Apple button.

However both buttons are drawn the same height despite using `grid.addWidget(appleBtn, 0, 0, 5, 1)` to define its height.

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys


def main():

    app     = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w       = QTabWidget()

    # Tab
    grid = QGridLayout()
    tab = QWidget() 
    tab.setLayout(grid)
    w.addTab(tab,"Hello World")


    # Button 1
    appleBtn = QPushButton("Apples")
    appleBtn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)   
    grid.addWidget(appleBtn, 0, 0, 5, 1)


    # Button 1
    orangeBtn = QPushButton("Oranges")
    appleBtn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)   
    grid.addWidget(orangeBtn, 5, 0, 1, 1)


    # Table
    fruitTable = QTableWidget()
    fruitTable.setRowCount(5)
    fruitTable.setColumnCount(2)
    fruitTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Fruit;Color;").split(";"))
    fruitTable.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
    grid.addWidget(fruitTable, 6, 0, 1, 1)


    w.resize(400,300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addWidget` method doesn't work in the way you assume it does. The second and third arguments specify the row/column, whilst the third and fourth specify how many rows/columns to span.

The correct way to specify proportional heights is with `setRowStretch`:

```
grid.addWidget(appleBtn, 0, 0)
grid.setRowStretch(0, 5)
...
grid.addWidget(orangeBtn, 1, 0)
...
grid.addWidget(fruitTable, 2, 0)
grid.setRowStretch(2, 5)
```